# Can "that" sometimes be superflous?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

For example, both of these sentences seem fine to me.

> I'll do everything I can to make sure she's happy.
>
> I'll do everything that I can to make sure that she's happy.

Is "that" *really* needed?

Comment: No, it's not. The complementizer _that_ introduces tensed clauses and can be deleted from a complement (noun) clause like the object clause of _make sure_, but it is necessary if the complement is the subject of the sentence. I.e, _that_ is necessary in _That he arrived late is unfortunate,_ but not in _It is unfortunate (that) he arrived late_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was confused for a moment at your comment, because I hadn't read the last part of the example sentence(s) carefully. In case you'd conversely skipped the first part, there's also a relativiser _that_ in there (which is of course similarly necessary if no relative pronoun is present to take the subject slot).

Comment: John, I have a question if you don't mind, sir. I'm new here and I've noticed that some people will answer the question in a comment instead of submitting an actual answer. Is there some rule of etiquette I've missed? I'm trying to understand why this is. Your answer here seems excellent, so I am wondering why you simply left a comment.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: @cliff900 This is often a (site-)political rather than an English language issue. This question has appeared and been answered many times already, and 'answering' it yet again would send out a wrong signal to users, not encouraging them to do sensible checking before submitting a duplicate question. Giving the answer in a 'comment' is a way to help people while not encouraging misuse. // In John Lawler's case, I'm guessing he left politics way behind, and was very glad to do so.

Comment: @cliff900 Because I've answered this question [several dozen times before](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+delete+complementizer+that+tensed+clause) here, and I get tired of fussing with the Official Answer stuff. Nobody ever checks them, they just keep asking the same questions.